How to run this Apex Class with a master-detail object quoteline. - Trying to set up Advanced Approvals
Zero Apex experience, I just followed this documentation:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_enable_aa.htm&type=5
It states you can set up advanced approvals on other objects, the issue is I picked an object with a master-detail relationship to Quotes, the quote line. On Line 19 (where there is an "insert quoteline;" in the testRecall) I add a quoteline, but I need to add value to the quoteline before this, or at least that is what SF support is telling me.
Anyone know how to do this ?
@isTest
private class QuoteLineExtControllerTests {
    
    testMethod static void testSubmit() {
        SBQQ__QuoteLine__c quoteLine = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c();
        insert quoteLine;
        
        Test.startTest();
        QuoteLineExtController con = new QuoteLineExtController(new ApexPages.StandardController(quoteLine));
        con.onSubmit();
        quoteLine = [SELECT ApprovalStatus__c FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c WHERE Id = :quoteLine.Id LIMIT 1];
        Test.stopTest();
        
        System.assertEquals('Approved', quoteLine.ApprovalStatus__c);
    }
    
    testMethod static void testRecall() {
        SBQQ__QuoteLine__c quoteLine = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c();
        insert quoteLine;
        
        Test.startTest();
        QuoteLineExtController con = new QuoteLineExtController(new ApexPages.StandardController(quoteLine));
        con.onRecall();
        quoteLine = [SELECT ApprovalStatus__c FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c WHERE Id = :quoteLine.Id LIMIT 1];
        Test.stopTest();
        
        System.assertEquals('Recalled', quoteLine.ApprovalStatus__c);
    }
}

related class
public with sharing class QuoteLineExtController {
    private Id quoteLineId;
    public QuoteLineExtController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        quoteLineId = stdController.getId();
    }
    public PageReference onSubmit() {
        if (quoteLineId != null) {
            SBAA.ApprovalAPI.submit(quoteLineId, SBAA__Approval__c.Quote_Line__c);
        }
        return new PageReference('/' + quoteLineId);
    }
    public PageReference onRecall() {
        if (quoteLineId != null) {
            SBAA.ApprovalAPI.recall(quoteLineId, SBAA__Approval__c.Quote_Line__c);
        }
        return new PageReference('/' + quoteLineId);
    }
}

Attempting to follow this documentation:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_enable_aa.htm&type=5
replaced Quote with my orgs custom object SBQQ_QuoteLine_c
